# Custom element inside foreach have not expected model in knockout

Tags: knockout.js, custom-element

New to knockout I am trying to build-up a POC for custom elements.

Models are simple, a MainModel contains an array of LinkModel.

Goal is to iterate through the array of links to display 1 custom element "settings-view-link" for each LinkModel object.

```js
function LinkModel(params) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(params.name);
}

function MainModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.links = ko.observableArray([
        new LinkModel({ name: "link1"}),
        new LinkModel({ name: "link2"})
    ]);
};

$(function () {
    //registration of the custom element
    ko.components.register('settings-view-link', 
    { 
      viewModel: LinkModel, 
      template: "<div><strong data-bind='text: name'></strong></div>" 
    });
    ko.applyBindings(new MainModel());
});
```

```html
<div>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: links">
         <p data-bind="text: name"></p> <!-- handled correctly -->
         <settings-view-link></settings-view-link> <!-- handled not the way I expect-->
     </ul>
</div>
```

What I see is that if in the custom element I need to use $parent. to have my data-bind working as expected. Using

```html
<div><strong data-bind='text: $parent.name'></strong></div>
```

instead of

```html
<div><strong data-bind='text: name'></strong></div>
```

makes appear the name of my links on the web page.

I expected that inside the custom element it handles a LinkModel object but it is not, it is somehow a "submodel".
Can someone explain why I have to use $parent? Code is wrong but why? I really expect to have a LinkModel object Inside my custom element.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your custom component specifies a `viewModel` option, knockout will create a new instance of this viewmodel for you. You can omit the property and knockout will bind the component to the provided parameters:

> Components usually have viewmodels, but they don’t necessarily have to. A component can specify just a template. In this case, the object to which the component’s view is bound is the params object that you passed to the component binding

Source: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html#note-template-only-components

This example might better explain what I mean. The first component specifies a viewmodel function which is instantiated and bound to the component instance.

The second component passes `$data` as a parameter and basically works as a template. You might only need the template binding if you don't want to automatically create new viewmodels.

```js
var instanceCounter = 0;

var ViewModel = function() {
  this.nr = instanceCounter++;
}

ko.components.register('testComponent1', {
  viewModel: ViewModel,
  template: '<div data-bind="text: nr"></div>'
});

ko.components.register('testComponent2', {
  template: '<div data-bind="text: nr"></div>'
});


ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>


<section>
  <h2>New instance for each component</h2>
  <div data-bind='component: {
    name: "testComponent1"
}'></div>
  <div data-bind='component: {
    name: "testComponent1"
}'></div>
  <div data-bind='component: {
    name: "testComponent1"
}'></div>
</section>

<section>
  <h2>Same instance for each component</h2>
  <div data-bind='component: {
    name: "testComponent2",
    params: $data
}'></div>
  <div data-bind='component: {
    name: "testComponent2",
    params: $data
}'></div>
  <div data-bind='component: {
    name: "testComponent2",
    params: $data
}'></div>
</section>
```